# WHY my <input file> overflows my grid container?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I have a custom file input element inside a 4 column grid container and a 16px gap where I keep my inputs. My problem is when I choose a file with a long name like `"XXXXX02000000SDD000D.pdf"`,
my custom input element grows so large that the `line-clamp` does not work and overflows my grid container. It happens that when I choose files with long names but with several words like `"my file called my beloved pdf.pdf"` the `line-clamp` works  and therefore my grid container does not overflow. Is the problem my entrance or my container?

When I choose files with long names but with multiple words:

[image: when I choose files with long names but with multiple words]

I choose a file with a big word with no spaces and my container overflows:

[image: I choose a file with a big word with no spaces and my container overflows]

My input file element

```
        <label className={`label`}>
            {props.label}
            <span className='file-input'>
                <span className='file-input__icon'><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>
                <span className='file-input__file-name'>
                    <span className='file-input__file-name-text'>{fileName}</span>
                </span>
                <input
                    className='file-input__input'
                    type='file'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    accept='.pdf' />
            </span>
        </label>
```

My Input file CSS

```
.file-input {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
    color: inherit;
}

.file-input:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px var(--soft-grey);
    outline: none;
}

.file-input__input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.file-input__icon {
    border: 1px solid var(--soft-grey);
    border-top-left-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
    border-bottom-left-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--very-soft-grey);
}

.file-input__file-name {
    border-right: 1px solid var(--soft-grey);
    border-top: 1px solid var(--soft-grey);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--soft-grey);
    border-top-right-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
    border-bottom-right-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.file-input__file-name-text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

My Grid Container

```
<div className='section__inputs-container'>
            <Input
                name='nombres'
                value={inputsData.nombres}
                label='Nombres'
                placeholder='Enrique Alegre'
                type='text'
            />
            // and more inputs ...
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.section__inputs-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: end;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put this class in the text container of my custom file input, for the property to cut long words and wrap around its container.

```
.file-input__file-name-text {
   >>>>>>>>>word-break: break-all;<<<<<<<<<<
   display: -webkit-box;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Long Word fits its container]